# SQL query slow calculating cumulative totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

We are storing data readings at 5 minute intervals for a large number of gauges.

The data tables involved are:

```
Table1 - GaugeData
Columns - 
    GaugeID (int, primary key)
    Timestamp (datetime, primary key)
    Value (decimal)

Table2 - GaugeSummaryData
Columns - 
    GaugeID (int, primary key)
    DayTimestamp (date, primary key)
    DayTotal (decimal) - total for the current date/day
    CumulativeTotal (decimal) - total up to and including the current date
```

Without changing the table structure in any way, what would be the most efficient way to copy and aggregate data from GaugeData into GaugeSummaryData?

I have attempted this two ways already. Using a cursor takes 40 minutes to copy all data from GaugeData to GaugeSummaryData. Using insert/update statements took 2hrs+.

Could somebody please suggest the most efficient way? Pseudocode or SQL appreciated.

Comment: How much data do you have? 10MB? 100GB?

Comment: Have you used the SQL Profiler to see what parts of the query are taking the most time?

Answer (score 1):

5GB is not that much data. I would say that your tables could use some new indexes.  Once those are in place, insert triggers should do the job very nicely.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_INS_GaugeData ON GaugeData FOR INSERT AFTER
AS
BEGIN
    -- create new GaugeSummaryData rows for dates that are not in table yet
    INSERT GaugeSummaryData (GaugeID, DayTimestamp, DayTotal, CumulativeTotal)
    SELECT I.GaugeID, CONVERT(date, I.TimeStamp), 0, SUM(GT.DayTotal)
    FROM INSERTED AS I
    INNER JOIN GaugeSummaryData GT ON I.GaugeID = GT.GaugeID AND convert(date, I.TimeStamp) < GT.DayTimestamp
    GROUP BY I.GaugeID, convert(date, I.TimeStamp)
    -- update GaugeSummaryData rows with totals
    UPDATE GSD
    SET DayTotal = DayTotal+I.Value, CumulativeTotal = CumulativeTotal + I.Value
    From INSERTED AS I
    INNER JOIN GaugeSummaryData GT ON I.GaugeID = GT.GaugeID
          and convert(date, I.TimeStamp) = GT.DayTimestamp
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to update the GaugeSummaryData at the end of each day only once? If its not, then probably applying an after insert trigger on Gauge Data should make the whole process real time and less time consuming. As soon as an entry is made in Gauge Data, the trigger will update the corresponding entry in GaugeSummaryData. If its the first entry for the day, then trigger should reset the Day Total to 0 before updating.